# java8 stream collect different list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I want to convert the input list to different list after filter. Please let know how to implement in java8 stream.

I tried something like below, it gave compilation error "p cannot be resolved to a variable" in getOutput() in collect().

```
List<Output> outputList= inputList.stream()
                    .filter(p ->  p.param1==10)                     
                    .collect(Collectors.toList(getOutput(p)));  


private Output getOutput(Input inp){
 Output out = new Output();
 out.value1= inp.value1;
 ---
 ---
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `map`.

Comment: can you please explain more what you mean by that?

Comment: Refer to this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. It explains it.

Comment: `toList()` signature doesn't take any argument. Answer posted by @George should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by the comments you can do something like this

```
List<Output> outputList= inputList.stream()
                    .filter(p ->  p.param1==10) 
                    .map(j -> getOutput(j))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So after the filter you convert the objects to your other type and finally collect. Alternatively, you can use the mapping collector to transform your objects into another kind and then collect them like below

```
List<Output> outputList= inputList.stream()
        .filter(p ->  p.param1==10) 
        .collect(Collectors.mapping(j -> getOutput(j), Collectors.toList()));
```